# SVG Animation - How can I reverse the start and end points in this svg path?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

So I am creating some kind of small animations for icons. I want to stick svg as they are just some small line animations.

The .svg is in the html document. The css has the styles for the lines and the animation.

https://jsfiddle.net/pd9ux6e7/

So now what I got. I got this drawing line, just like I wanted it. The only thing that bothers me is the way the animation start and ends. Now it goes from bottom right to top left. But I want to have it from top left to bottom right (just like how you read, from left to right feels much more natural)

Any idea how I can fix this? I think it's somewhere in the svg path but idk what these values stand for. This is the blue line in svg `<path class="st3" d="M1194.1,777.2H7c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V35.9" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've reversed the path and this reversed the animation. Also the path's length is 1932 so in the css i'm using this value instead.

```css
.st0 {
  fill: #ffffff;
}

.st1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #afafaf;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st2 {
  fill: #ffffff;
  stroke: #afafaf;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st3 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #2646ff;
  stroke-width: 7;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

#Streep .st3 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1932;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: dash 8s ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1932;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1200 780" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1200 780;" xml:space="preserve">
          <g id="Layer_1"></g>
          <g id="Layer_6">
            <g>
              <g>
                <path
                  class="st0"
                  d="M1198,772.2c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5H7c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V36.6c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5h1186c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5V772.2z"
                />
                <path
                  class="st1"
                  d="M1198,772.2c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5H7c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V36.6c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5h1186c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5V772.2z"
                />
              </g>
              <line class="st1" x1="2" y1="688.2" x2="1198" y2="688.2" />
              <ellipse class="st2" cx="559.9" cy="732.7" rx="16.9" ry="16.7" />
            </g>
          </g>
          <g id="Layer_5">
            <g>
              <g>
                <path
                  class="st0"
                  d="M1127.3,771.9c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5H631.5c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V194.2c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5h490.8c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5V771.9z"
                />
                <path
                  class="st1"
                  d="M1127.3,771.9c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5H631.5c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V194.2c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5h490.8c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5V771.9z"
                />
              </g>
              <line class="st1" x1="626.5" y1="715.5" x2="1127.3" y2="715.5" />
            </g>
          </g>
          <g id="Layer_4">
            <g>
              <g>
                <path
                  class="st0"
                  d="M1198,771.9c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5H976.8c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V352.1c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5H1193c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5V771.9z"
                />
                <path
                  class="st1"
                  d="M1198,771.9c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5H976.8c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V352.1c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5H1193c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5V771.9z"
                />
              </g>
              <line class="st1" x1="971.8" y1="732" x2="1198" y2="732" />
            </g>
          </g>
          <g id="Streep">
            <g>
              <path class="st3" d="M2,35.9L2,772.2 C2,775 4.2,777.2 7,777.2 L1194.1,777.2" />
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
```

Comment: Damn nailed it. Could you explain it a bit more on where to find the path length? And how exactly did you find the path positions? Thanks!!

Comment: In order to get the path length you may use `thePath.getTotalLength()` method where `thePath` represents the path whose's length you want to get

Comment: Thanks! And how did you actually revert the path in the svg?

Comment: The idea is that you begin the path on the ending path. First I transformed the commands to upper case. Next I transformed H and V commands to L. After this I've used the last point as the first. To reverse the C command I draw a line to the last point and reversed the control points. The last point of the curve is now the ending point of the first line. Finaly I draw a line to the previous first point.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to reverse the path definition.  Just reverse the dashoffset animation.

```
#Streep .st3 {
    stroke-dasharray: 1932;
    stroke-dashoffset: -1932;
    animation: dash 8s ease-in-out;
    animation-direction: forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

This will work in most browsers, but unfortunately not Safari, which has a bug where it doesn't accept negative dashoffsets.

To work around that, just shift your dashoffset values up by (dashlength + dashgap) = 1932 + 1932 = 3864.

```
#Streep .st3 {
    stroke-dasharray: 1932;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1932;
    animation: dash 8s ease-in-out;
    animation-direction: forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 3864;
  }
}
```

The result:

```css
svg { width: 500px; }
.st0 {
              fill: #ffffff;
    }

.st1 {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #afafaf;
              stroke-width: 4;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
            }

            .st2 {
              fill: #ffffff;
              stroke: #afafaf;
              stroke-width: 4;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
            }

            .st3 {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #2646ff;
              stroke-width: 7;
              stroke-linecap: round;
              stroke-linejoin: round;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
            }

#Streep .st3 {
    stroke-dasharray: 1932;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1932;
    animation: dash 8s ease-in-out;
    animation-direction: forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 3864;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg
          version="1.1"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          x="0px"
          y="0px"
          viewBox="0 0 1200 780"
          style="enable-background:new 0 0 1200 780;"
          xml:space="preserve"
        >
          <g id="Layer_1"></g>
          <g id="Layer_6">
            <g>
              <g>
                <path
                  class="st0"
                  d="M1198,772.2c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5H7c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V36.6c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5h1186c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5V772.2z"
                />
                <path
                  class="st1"
                  d="M1198,772.2c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5H7c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V36.6c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5h1186c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5V772.2z"
                />
              </g>
              <line class="st1" x1="2" y1="688.2" x2="1198" y2="688.2" />
              <ellipse class="st2" cx="559.9" cy="732.7" rx="16.9" ry="16.7" />
            </g>
          </g>
          <g id="Layer_5">
            <g>
              <g>
                <path
                  class="st0"
                  d="M1127.3,771.9c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5H631.5c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V194.2c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5h490.8c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5V771.9z"
                />
                <path
                  class="st1"
                  d="M1127.3,771.9c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5H631.5c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V194.2c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5h490.8c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5V771.9z"
                />
              </g>
              <line class="st1" x1="626.5" y1="715.5" x2="1127.3" y2="715.5" />
            </g>
          </g>
          <g id="Layer_4">
            <g>
              <g>
                <path
                  class="st0"
                  d="M1198,771.9c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5H976.8c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V352.1c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5H1193c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5V771.9z"
                />
                <path
                  class="st1"
                  d="M1198,771.9c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5H976.8c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V352.1c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5H1193c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5V771.9z"
                />
              </g>
              <line class="st1" x1="971.8" y1="732" x2="1198" y2="732" />
            </g>
          </g>
          <g id="Streep">
            <g>
              <path class="st3" d="M1194.1,777.2H7c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V35.9" />
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
```

Comment: Damn. thanks, I fixed it with the other guy his suggestion though now